# Show a different picture for a different value

Tags: microsoft-excel

For an excel cell, I would like to show Image1 if A1 = 1 and show Image2 if A1 = 2.  Is there a way of doing that?

Answer (score 2):

if you are using excel 2007 or later, it now offers conditional formatting with a pre-canned set of icon images
[image]

If none of these suit, there is a vba solution to this at this [MrExcel](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/showthread.php?t=55037) page.

Comment: For some standard use scenarios, like 'is this form fully filled out?', this is infinitely easier than the maddeningly complex solutions bandied about on the web.  
  
In Excel 2010 you will find 'Conditional Formatting' on the 'Home' part of the ribbon. Click it and choose 'Icons' or 'Icon sets' or something to that effect.